# numSlices in a call to parallelize is overridden by a coalesce that follows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
index = sc.parallelize(range(1000), 100)
huge_rows = index.map(heavy_processing)
schema = StructType([StructField('f1', BinaryType(), False), StructField('f2', BinaryType(), False)])

bbox2d_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(huge_rows, schema)
bbox2d_dataframe = bbox2d_dataframe.coalesce(1)
bbox2d_dataframe.write.option("compression", "none").mode('overwrite').parquet('/tmp/huge/')
```

I would expect the processing to be parallelized into 100 tasks (since numSlices=100 in the call to parallelize),
so that heavy_processing be better parallelized.
However, I see only a single task in SparkUI. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's to be expected since you've called `coalesce(1)`. Per the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce) it's going to return a DataFrame with the number of partitions specified (in your case 1). If you want the `heavy_processing` to be more distributed but then want to write out a single file then use `repartition(1)` so it introduces a shuffle boundary and leaves the 1st stage at 100 partitions.